# Unsure of what ESLint rule to turn off

Tags: javascript, mongoose, eslint, prettier

I have been working on an application and recently wrote a Mongoose aggregate query to return some data to an API. My workspace is setup using prettier and eslint.

Here is my `.eslintrc`

```
 {
  "extends": ["plugin:prettier/recommended"],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 8,
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true
    },
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": ["error", {
      "singleQuote": true
    }],
    "max-len": 0

  }
}
```

I have prettier set to ignore `js` files and have eslint handle them. The resulting code looks like this after formatting by eslint.

```
// rehire by employee ID
app.get('/employee/:empID', (req, res) => {
  const empID = req.params.empID;
  Rehires.aggregate(
    [
      { $match: { 'data.EMPLOYEE_ID': empID } },
      {
        $project: {
          data: {
            $filter: {
              input: '$data',
              as: 'data',
              cond: { $eq: ['$$data.EMPLOYEE_ID', empID] }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    (err, employees) => {
      // check if employees
      if (!employees || employees.length === 0) {
        return res.status(404).json({
          error: `No rehire file(s) exist that contain an Employee ID of ${empID}`
        });
      }
      //employees exist
      return res.json(employees);
    }
  );
});
```

I am unsure of what eslint rules to turn off so this isn't 30 lines of code. What rules enforce all these newlines?

Comment: All which newlines? There's only a single place I *might* relax "all those newlines". This is what clean JS code looks like. What's your issue with it? And why use prettier if you don't want it to look like this?

Comment: Maybe It's more for understanding than a don't like it.

Answer (score 2):

Format the code like you want, use `eslint` **without** the [`--fix` option](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#fixing-problems), and it should report all the offending syntax with a mention of the respective rule.

My guess (I didn't try it) would be [`function-paren-newline`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/function-paren-newline), [`curly`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/curly), [`object-curly-newline`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/object-curly-newline) and [`object-property-newline`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/object-property-newline).